# haskell couchdb-conduit example

Tags: haskell, couchdb

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Db (
    couchTest
) where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Generics (Data, Typeable)
import Database.CouchDB.Conduit
import Database.CouchDB.Conduit.Generic

conn :: CouchConnection
conn = def {couchLogin = "admin", couchPass = "admin"}

data D = D { f1 :: Int, f2 :: String } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

couchTest = runCouch conn $ do
    rev1 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" "" [] $ D 123 "str"
    rev2 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" rev1 [] $ D 1234 "another"
    (rev3, d1 :: D) <- couchGet "mydb" "my-doc1" []
    liftIO $ print d1
    couchPut' "mydb" "my-doc1" [] $ D 12345 "third"    -- notice - no rev
    rev3 <- couchRev "mydb" "my-doc1"
    couchDelete "mydb" "my-doc1" rev3
```

error

```
No instance for (monad-control-0.3.1.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
                   IO m0)
  arising from a use of `couchPut'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for
  (monad-control-0.3.1.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl
     IO m0)
In the expression: couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" "" []
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  rev1 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" "" [] $ D 123 "str"
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { rev1 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" "" [] $ D 123 "str";
        rev2 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" rev1 [] $ D 1234 "another";
        (rev3, d1 :: D) <- couchGet "mydb" "my-doc1" [];
        liftIO $ print d1;
        .... }'
```

1) How do you add an instance declaration for `monad-control-0.3.1.3:Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl IO m0`?

2) Is it possible to create attachments with couchdb-conduit?

3) Is there a example of using couchdb directly with http package, basically to see how much code it takes?

Comment: 1) out of pure luck i found out adding `couchTest:: IO ()` as type signature works? Which is really confusing especially with `liftIO $ print d1`

Comment: `liftIO` if you're already in the `IO` monad is well supported, it just doesn't do anything: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.3.0.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#liftIO

Comment: However the `liftIO` in your example code is required because `runCouch` runs an action (effectively) in `ResourceT IO`, not `IO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be better to split your question up since you're asking three different things. As far as #1 goes, no new instance is required for MonadBaseControl. Add type signatures to remove the ambiguity and it compiles straight away:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, FlexibleContexts,
             OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Db (
    couchTest
) where

import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO, liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (MonadThrow, MonadUnsafeIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control (MonadBaseControl)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Generics (Data, Typeable)
import Database.CouchDB.Conduit
import Database.CouchDB.Conduit.Generic

conn :: CouchConnection
conn = def {couchLogin = "admin", couchPass = "admin"}

data D = D { f1 :: Int, f2 :: String } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

couchTest
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadUnsafeIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadBaseControl IO m)
  => m ()
-- couchTest :: IO () -- restricting it to IO is also an option
couchTest = runCouch conn $ do
    rev1 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" "" [] $ D 123 "str"
    rev2 <- couchPut "mydb" "my-doc1" rev1 [] $ D 1234 "another"
    (rev3, d1 :: D) <- couchGet "mydb" "my-doc1" []
    liftIO $ print d1
    couchPut' "mydb" "my-doc1" [] $ D 12345 "third"    -- notice - no rev
    rev3 <- couchRev "mydb" "my-doc1"
    couchDelete "mydb" "my-doc1" rev3
```

I had GHC come up with the constraint list for me by enabling the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` language pragma and running the following in GHCi. You can also leave the NMR flag set in many cases instead of adding explicit signatures, but I prefer explicit signatures.

```
*Db> :info couchTest 
couchTest ::
  (MonadIO m, Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadUnsafeIO m,
   Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.MonadThrow m,
   MonadBaseControl IO m) =>
  m ()
    -- Defined at /tmp/cdb.hs:21:5
```

Comment: can I bother you with a simmalar type question pleas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731941/haskell-facebook-exceptions